# Alternative to calling a task from within a task, Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a custom Gradle plugin that will generate Java files from a template file. I have several such template files in different locations, and I need to "compile" all of them to generate the Java files I need. Once I have the files, I want to package them into a .jar.

My first thought was that I'd execute the "compile" task from the custom plugin from within other tasks. Something like:

```
task compileFromLocationA <<{
    compileTemplate.execute()...
}

task compileFromLocationB
    ...

packageJar(depends: compileFromLocationA, compileFromLocationB)
    ...
```

However, you can't programmatically call a task from within another task. I've heard I might be able to get around this using `dependsOn` or `finalizedBy`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply those keywords here. What's the "best practice" for something like this? I'm new to Gradle and haven't been able to get very far using the official docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dependsOn` to accomplish this.
Here is an example:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task taskA <<{
    println 'task A'
}

task taskB (type:Copy){
    println 'B'
}

task taskC (type:Copy){
    println 'C'
}
task taskBC (dependsOn:['taskB','taskC'])<<{
    println 'BC'
}
taskBC.mustRunAfter taskA
```

You can also use `mustRunAfter` to insure a task always runs after another task.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how I could use this pattern to, say, run taskA more than once. I need to run the "compile template" task multiple times.

Comment: At the time of this comment there wasn't any reference to 'run more than once'

Comment: "I'd execute the "compile" task from the custom plugin from within other task*s*". I'll edit to make this clearer.

Comment: I think the original question you asked, which was answered is a valid one. I would suggest keeping the question as is and accept the answer. Ask a new question on how to invoke a custom take multiple times. Both are good questions.

Comment: Provide a link to the new question. I would be happy to help you solve it.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324710/calling-the-same-task-multiple-times-in-a-single-build-gradle-file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can have:

**1) Some functionality wrapped up in "normal" Groovy functions:**

```
def doSomething() {
  // ...
}

task taskA {
  description = 'Description for this task'
  doLast {
    doSomething()
  }
}
```

**2) Make use of `mustRunAfter` between tasks (careful, this can become messy, depending on your config size)**

```
task taskA {
  description = 'Description for task A'
  doLast {
    // ...
  }
}

task taskB {
  description = 'Description for task B'
  doLast {
    // ...
  }
}

taskB.mustRunAfter taskA
```

**3) Make use of `dependsOn` between tasks**

```
task taskA {
  description = 'Description for task A'
  doLast {
    // ...
  }
}

task taskB(dependsOn: taskA) {
  description = 'Description for task B'
  doLast {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: So I could have the "compile the template file" logic inside of `doSomething()`? I can see how that would work, although I like the idea of keeping the compile logic in a separate plugin so I can reuse it more easily.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how I could use these pattern to, say, run taskA more than once. I need to run the "compile template" task multiple times.