# Calling the same task multiple times in a single build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, plugins

I have a custom Gradle plugin that will generate Java files from a template file. I have several such template files in different locations, and I need to "compile" all of them to generate the Java files I need. Once I have the files, I want to package them into a .jar.

One way I thought I could do this was to call the "compile template" task multiple times from within the same build file. I'd call it once in a task that compiles template files in location A, again from a task that compiles template files from location B... etc., until I have all the Java files I need.

Something like this:

```
task compileFromLocationA <<{
    compileTemplate.execute(A)...
}

task compileFromLocationB
    compileTemplate.execute(B)...

...

packageJar(depends: compileFromLocationA, compileFromLocationB, ...)
    ...
```

However, you can't programmatically call a task from within another task. I suppose I could break each `compileFromLocation_` task into it's own `build.gradle` file, but that seems like overkill. What's the "best practice" in a case like this?

Comment: To get a better understanding: Are your template files that are in multiple locations in known locations? Also, the custom plugin, is it your own that you created? Meaning you have control of the source code for the plugin?

Comment: Yes and yes. There are 6 or 7 places I need to get template files from, but I know them all. As for the plugin, I didn't write it, but I have access to the source.

Comment: If it's a plugin, then it provides a custom task type? Does it also define properties like 'source' where it will look for the files to generate templates from?

Comment: It provides a single custom task, `compileTemplateFile`. It doesn't define a property like 'source', it just looks in the location of the `build.umple` file. I may be able to configure it to include a `source` property though.

Comment: If it only looks at the bulid.umple file, why not dynamically build that file with multiple sources as one task and then invoke the plugin in a separate task that depends on the first task that builds the file? Assuming the file can have multiple sources? That would be one option that doesn't require any plugin modification.

Comment: So the idea would be to get all the template files into one location, and then run the plugin once at that location? Why would I need to dynamically build `build.umple` to do that? Couldn't I write some static task that collects all the template files?

Comment: You can create tasks dynamically as you need in a loop for example that checks for the file and then creates a task for that location. Just write the groovy code for the lookup and put the task definition inside the loop. But make sure that you set different tasks names and that in the best case they are the same every run. But want to mentions that only if this is possible it's not a way you should write gradle setups!

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work in `build.gradle` by using `tasks.register()` - e.g. to perform multiple source code generating steps - in my case I needed to load different pairs of files (XML schema and generation options) in two different steps:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.plugin" version "1.0"
}


sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += file("${buildDir}/genSrc")
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs += file("${buildDir}/testGenSrc")

tasks.compileJava {
    dependsOn tasks.named("genMessage")
}

genMessage {
    codesFile = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/file.xml"
}

def testGenModel1 = tasks.register("testGenModel1", com.plugin.TestGenModelTask.class) {
    schema = "${projectDir}/src/test/resources/file.xsd"
    options = "${projectDir}/src/test/resources/file.xml"
}

def testGenModel2 = tasks.register("testGenModel2", com.plugin.TestGenModelTask.class) {
    schema = "${projectDir}/src/test/resources/file2.xsd"
    options = "${projectDir}/src/test/resources/file2.xml"
}

tasks.compileTestJava {
    dependsOn tasks.named("testGenModel1"), tasks.named("testGenModel2")
}
```